# C programming decimal to binary - adding leading zero to recursive method

Tags: c, recursion, binary, formatting, decimal

I have a recursive method to convert a decimal number to a binary number in C

```
long decimalToBinary(long n)
{
    if(n == 0) {
      return 0;
    } 
    else {
      return (10*decimalToBinary(n/2))+(n%2);

    }
}
```

It is printing out the correct output, but i'm trying to have it place leading zero's and before the binary number if it is not divisible by 4 and print it out in groups of `4`. (eg. `100101100` -> `0001 0010 1100`)

I was thinking about using an array, and instead of returning the answer like I am now, putting it into an array and modifying it up in the `main()` method. Then I could add a space and add zeros in the beginning.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is - use a `char` array. Well you mentioned it and there is no way you can convert it to binary using some standard functions **directly**.

Comment: Thanks @coderredoc. The issue that I am having with using an array , is that I don't know what size of number I will have. It is a random input. How would I make an array that fills without a predetermined size?

Comment: Well that problem has a well known solution - allocate memory dynamically at the beginning so that it can hold maximum digits(as needed by your application) and then in case there is further need for expansion or shrinking reallocate. And more than that taking a 100 element `char` would be enough I would say.

Comment: "I don't know what size of number I will have" --> Could use something like `ceil(log(LONG_MAX)/log(2))`

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].  The code you show doesn't print anything.  Your `decimalToBinary` function takes a binary number and returns a binary number.  `int binary=10; // decimal to binary!`.  Your code converts the number 10 decimal (0x0a b1010) to 1010 decimal (0x03f2 or b1111110010), your debugger is probably translating it for you to decimal, but that's usually configurable.  The rubber meets the road where you actually write the code to convert a binary value to a string of 1's and zero's, and include pretty stuff like the leading 'b', nibble groups and zero padding.

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In `decimalToBinary`, instead of creating a decimal value, you can create a `char` array. This `char` array will contain the binary digits in reverse order, so when you print the array in your `main` function, you need to print them in reverse order.

The `decimalToBinary` will look like:

```
char *decimalToBinary(long n)
{
  int rem, mult = -1, i = 0, len = 5;
  char *arr = (char *) calloc(len, sizeof(char));

  // Loop until multiplier is not 0
  while (mult != 0) {
    mult = n / 2;
    rem = n % 2;
    n = mult;

    // If we are approaching end of string, increase its size
    if (mult != 0 && i == len) {
        len += 4;
        arr = (char *) realloc(arr, len);
    }

    arr[i++] = rem + '0'; // Convert int to char
  }
  arr[i] = '\0'; // End-of-string character

  return arr;
}
```

You can then call this function from `main` and print it like this:

```
// Convert decimal to binary (char array)
char *arr = decimalToBinary(n);

// Print leading 0s
int len = strlen(arr);
int padding = (len % 4) == 0 ? 0 : 4 - (len % 4);
int count = 0;
while (padding > 0) {
    printf("0");
    --padding;
    ++count;
}

// Print the binary digits in reverse 
int i = len - 1;
while (i >= 0) {
    // Print a space after every 4 chars
    if (count > 0 && count % 4 == 0) {
        printf(" ");
    }

    printf("%c", arr[i]);
    --i;
    ++count;
}
printf("\n");
```

I've tried this code out and it works. For example, the decimal number `280` will print out as `0001 0001 1000`.